# React state reference within onClick is wrong - possible closure issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is a stripped down version of a React component that I have. It is a home screen with an intro animation, that will automatically end and fade out after a timeout, but can also be skipped by the user.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Home() {
  const [introEnded, setIntroEnded] = useState(false);

  // function to end intro animation
  function endIntro() {
    console.log(introEnded); // THIS IS WRONG THE SECOND TIME FUNCTION IS CALLED
    if (!introEnded) {
      setIntroEnded(true);
      // do various other stuff
    }
    // do various other stuff
  }

  // if user does not interact, intro ends automatically
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      endIntro();
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  // user can skip intro on click
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={endIntro}>Skip Intro</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is, after a user skips, when the timeout kicks in and calls `endIntro()` a second time, the `introEnded` state is wrong. I have clearly set it to true the first time `endIntro()` was called, yet the second call to `endIntro()` seems to reference an older state.

Research tells me it's some sort of closure issue, but I can't work out the solution.

What's going on, and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: So i will conclude when the application loads you call the animation so it starts animating now user clicks on skip but the animation still works, so you need to cancel the ongoing animation which is going to end within 4 seconds is that whats your issue

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-meadow-tl5pv

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a Javascript closure issue. the value of variable introEnded is false when useEffect is called and this's not avoidable. In order to achieve this goal, we need to write some manual code like below.

```js
export function Home() {
  const [introEnded, setIntroEnded] = useState(false);
  const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState(0);
  const start = React.useMemo(() => {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }, []);

  // function to end intro animation
  const endIntro = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log(introEnded); // THIS IS WRONG THE SECOND TIME FUNCTION IS CALLED
    if (!introEnded) {
      setIntroEnded(true);
      // do various other stuff
    }
    // do various other stuff
  }, [introEnded]);

  // if user does not interact, intro ends automatically
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(elapsed);
    let timerId = -1
    if (4000 > elapsed) {
      timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        endIntro();
      }, 4000 - elapsed);
    }

    return () => {
      setElapsed(new Date().getTime() - start);
      if (timerId > 0) clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [elapsed, endIntro, start]);

  // user can skip intro on click
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={endIntro}>Skip Intro</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think this is the general use case and we can write our custom hook.

```js
// custom hook
const useInterruptibleTimeout = (timeout, handler) => {
  const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState(0);
  const start = React.useMemo(() => {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(elapsed);
    let timerId = -1
    if (timeout > elapsed) {
      timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        handler();
      }, timeout - elapsed);
    }

    return () => {
      setElapsed(new Date().getTime() - start);
      if (timerId > 0) clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [elapsed, handler, start, timeout]);


}

export function Home() {
  const [introEnded, setIntroEnded] = useState(false);

  // function to end intro animation
  const endIntro = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log(introEnded); // THIS IS WRONG THE SECOND TIME FUNCTION IS CALLED
    if (!introEnded) {
      setIntroEnded(true);
      // do various other stuff
    }
    // do various other stuff
  }, [introEnded]);

  useInterruptibleTimeout(4000, endIntro)

  // user can skip intro on click
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={endIntro}>Skip Intro</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope this code helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call the entire function inside `useEffect` you can just update your intro `state`.

Also you might need to return a cleanup function that will reset your `state` back to `false` at the end of your `useEffect` which will simulate the `componentWillUnmount()`. Read more here [cleaning up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

```js
const App = () => {
  const [introEnded, setIntroEnded] = React.useState(false);
  // function to end intro animation
  function endIntro() {
    setIntroEnded(true)
     // do your other stuff
     console.log('skipped')
  }

  // if user does not interact, intro ends automatically
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Change state after x second
    setTimeout(function() {
      setIntroEnded(true)
    }, 4000);
    // Clean up and set it back to false
    return () => setIntroEnded(false)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={endIntro}>Skip Intro</div>
      {!introEnded ? <div>Your Intro... This will end after 4 seconds..</div> : <div>Intro Ended... </div>} 
    </div>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Some tips you have to implement in your code:

1. clear timeout by returned id when the Home component destroyed.
2. using setState callback instead and checking before calling the function into setTimeout callback.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Home() {
  const [introEnded, setIntroEnded] = useState(false);

  // function to end intro animation
  function endIntro() {
    console.log(introEnded); // THIS IS WRONG THE SECOND TIME FUNCTION IS CALLED

    setIntroEnded(() => true);
    // do various other stuff
    // do various other stuff
  }

  // if user does not interact, intro ends automatically
  useEffect(() => {
    const setTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!introEnded) {
        endIntro();
      }
    }, 4000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(setTimeoutId);
    };
  }, []);

  // user can skip intro on click
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => endIntro()}>Skip Intro</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is an example: https://repl.it/@ali_master/reactSetTimeout